# ASPs from Testing Architecture

Tags: testing, service-provider

I need to know what is the purpose of the (N-1)-ASPs/PCO between the lower tester (LT) and the lower level service provider in this example :

[image]

Someone can help me to understand ?

Comment: Hi Jack! Could you tell me what book is this picture from?

Comment: I found it on google image, this is the closest I found for my problem.